# Django - Loggers are overwriting the previous log file along with the new one

Tags: python, django, logging, gunicorn

I am using Django logger for logging along with gunicorn workers. Currently, I am testing with 3 workers and I am using the TimedRotatingFileHandler. I configured when = m and interval = 1, I tried sending some 1000 requests and it is writing in the new file and overwriting the old file as well.

Here is my config from settings.py

```
'debug': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filename': BASE_DIR + '/Log/debug.log',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'when': 'M',
            'interval': 1,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
```

This will happen only if i use more than 1 gunicorn worker. But if I use 1 gunicorn worker this is not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using file-based handlers directly from multiple processes concurrently, which is what you get if you use `gunicorn` with this configuration. Instead, use a `SocketHandler` or `QueueHandler` to send logs from the webapp to a separate process which logs them to disk. The [Python logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) has more information and example code, which is too long to reproduce here.

Writing to a single file from multiple concurrent processes without them treading on each other isn't supported in Python (and a lot of other languages too).

Comment: Yes, you are correct.
I tried with the WatchedFileHandler and rotating logs using logrotate. It is perfectly working for me.

Comment: @Suresh Bear in mind that this approach also writes to one file from multiple processes, so you could run into the same issue again (the problem with concurrency issues is that they can be intermittent and hard to reproduce). I updated the logging cookbook documentation to suggest alternative approaches using a `SocketHandler` - that's what I use for this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You could use `ConcurrentLogHandler` package to fix it.

first install setuptools<58.0.0:

```
pip install setuptools~=57.5.0
```

then:

```
pip install ConcurrentLogHandler
```

after that change the config like that:

settings.py

```
from cloghandler import ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler

 'debug': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'filename': BASE_DIR + '/Log/debug.log',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    },
```

note that you should remove `when` and `interval`.